# Lemniscate is homeomorphic to the circle?

Tags: general-topology

Do you agree that a lemniscate (i.e. $\infty$) is homeomorphic to the circle if theses two curves are embedding in $\mathbb R^3$, but that this result is not true in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

I read somewhere that the lemniscate is never not homeomorphic to the circle, but I have doubt about this information (without context). So is my example correct ?

Comment: You read correctly. After all, it is only a matter of how the lemniscate is defined, *in the plane*.

Comment: If the you think of one edge of the lemniscate passing **over** the other then you could "unwind" it to be a circle.  But that is NOT what a true lemniscate is.  The there is not one line **over** another but the two lines actually intersect.

Comment: Impossible by the double point of the lemniscate

Answer (score 2):

They are of course not homeomorphic, but in $\mathbb R^3$, you have that $$\mathbb S^1\cong L/_{\sim}$$
where $L$ is the Lemniscate, and $\sim$ a relation of equivalence (the one that "glue the two circles of the lemniscate"... strange expression, but it's in fact very natural. Tell me if you want a draw). Now in $\mathbb R^2$ you can get the same bijection (between $L/_{\sim}$ and $\mathbb S^1$), but it will not be continuous. Therefore, it's not an homeomorphism (and there is no way to "glue continuously the two circle of the lemniscate to get a circle"). Therefore, they will not be homeomorphic.

I'm trying to be simple in my words, I hope it will help. Tell me if it doesn't.

Comment: I think the intuition is that to glue the two circles together, you have to rotate at least one of them through the additional dimension. You can't contort around in just two dimensions in order to get the two of them on top of each other without ripping the connection.

Answer (score 1):

What you read is correct. The lemniscate and and the circle are *intrinsically* non-homeomorphic, regardless in what space they are embedded.

The lemniscate has a cut-point (if we remove it, the remainder (two open intervals, essentially, is not connected) and the circle has not, and this will always result in the spaces not being homeomorphic.